# Obtaining list of property values from list of Person

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding

Using Visual Studio Express 2010 for Windows Phone | C# | Silverlight

I have this class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Spent { get; set; }
    public double Paid { get; set; }
}
```

And this list

```
public List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();`
```

I want to populate a listpicker with the Name values of peopleList. How do I do this without the use of DataTemplates?

From what I know, I can databind the listpicker ItemSource with `List<string>`. But I can't create another list of type string just for the names because they need to be synced at all times. Also I found many suggestions to use LINQ, but can this be used in WP7?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx)

Something like:

```
<ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding peopleList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: This is a more elegant and straightforward approach than my answer.

Comment: For some reason, the listpicker shows me the characters of the word "peoplelist", as in p, e, o, p, etc. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Make sure you're binding it right (StaticResource vs DataContext). I'm not quite sure of the syntax for WP7.

Comment: So what should I be going for, StaticResource or DataContext?

Comment: It depends on how you have your app structured. If you're using another class to hold the `peopleList` then you'll need to set the `DataContext` of the `ListPicker` or the container (e.g. `Page` or `Frame`) so it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding directly to the list, override the `ToString` method to just `return this.Name`.

Comment: Not an answer -- this should be a comment.